# simple algorithm with indexOf not working in JS

Tags: javascript

my mission is to find and output, where the tabs/word entered, is placed in the sentence.
the console gives me back that place var is not defined. What should I do? Thank you very much!

```js
var sentence = prompt("Enter you sentence");
var word = prompt("Enter the tabs/word you looking for");
var counter = 0;
var place = stntence.indexOf(word, counter);

if (stntence.indexOf(word) != -1) {
  while (place != -1) {
    if (place != -1) {
      console.log("The place of the word/tab is: " + place);
      counter = place++;
    } else {
      console.log("That's all")
    }
  }
} else {
  console.log("the word/tabs are not exist in the sentence");
}
```

Comment: `stntence.indexOf(word)` to `sentence.indexOf(word)` typo

Comment: `stntence` !== `sentence`.

Comment: except for the stuff mentioned by the other, your logic looks a bit weird, why the double indexOf, and why would the second indexOf be outside of the while loop?

Comment: @ArvindMaurya I didn't understand. What exactly the difference between them ?

Comment: @NinaScholz I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: @ArvindMaurya If the word not appears in the sentence, I can "save" the loop.

Comment: you have a typo in your code

Answer (score 0):

Beside the typo of `stntence !== sentence`, you could take the advantage of the counter and use a shortened approach by assigning the place directly in the `while` condition.

```js
var sentence = prompt("Enter you sentence"),
    word = prompt("Enter the tabs/word you looking for"),
    counter = 0,
    place = -1;

while ((place = sentence.indexOf(word, place + 1)) != -1) {
    console.log("The place of the word/tab is: " + place);
    counter++;
}

if (counter) {
    console.log("That's all");
} else {
    console.log("the word/tabs are not exist in the sentence");
}
```

Comment: Hey, I still don't get what you all mean by saying "sentence!==sentence". Can you give me please a simple explanation?

Comment: you have a wrong written variable, which makey prblems, because you need the exact same writing of a variable. you declare and initialize `sentence` and use later `stntence`, which is a different variable and this one is not initialized nor declared.

Comment: Sorry for annoying, but where I "restart" the variable? Can you show me, pleasie? I just can't see where I do it. Where the type/value is changed ?

Comment: sorry. why is **a** not **b**? because they are different. code has to be exact, not similar. the variable `sentence` is never used later. the value of it does not matter at all. you could delete the line with the declaration and initializion with the result of `prompt`. because you took `stntence` instead. this undeclared variable has no value. in sloppy environment, it has `undefined` and in strict environment, you get an error for using an undeclared variable.